# Process builder & Flows in AppEchange Apps allowed or not? Also, check in what editions of SF flows are allowed?

Tags: visual-workflow, process-builder, appexchange

Can anyone please reply, if we can use Flows in AppEchange Apps or not? Also, check in what editions of SF flows are allowed?

like, application created with the flows to some task(s) and process builder for another task.

Does following application only allowed in Enterprise & Unlimited Editions?

Or for Essential & Professional as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Flows can appear in packages and are "IP protected" so cannot be examined or modified by subscribers. The Flow Template mechanism is provided to allow subscribers to create their own flows from the packaged template and modify to their heart's content. You'll find some information around this in the [Spring '19 release notes](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_forcecom_isvforce_package_prevuilt_processes.htm&type=5&release=218).

Process builders can, likewise, be included.

In terms of editions, as per the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.flow_considerations_limit.htm&type=5) the following are supported:

> Essentials, Professional, Enterprise, Performance, Unlimited, and Developer Editions